# jq - generate list of dictionaries instead of list of strings

Tags: shell, jq

The following command:

`cat foo | jq -r '[.items[] | select(.metadata.random_field["foo/foo"] == "true") | .metadata.name]'`
results in

```
[
  "test_data"
]
```

I would like the following output to be:

```
[
  {"name":"test", "data":"test_data"}
]
```

foo

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items":[
              {
                 "metadata": {
                 "random_field": {
                    "foo/foo": "true"
                 },
                "creationTimestamp": "2022-03-09T21:54:08Z",
                "name": "test_data"
                }
              }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE: added test data so the point can be illustrated properly.

Comment: You need to provide sample input for people to be able to test their answers.

Comment: `jq -r '[.items[] | select(.field["foo/foo"] == "true") | {name:"test", data:.metadata.name}]'`

Comment: Let me update with sample input

Comment: Where does `"name":"test"` come from and where does `"data":"test_data"` come from? "data" in output == "name" in input? But which input value transforms to "name" in the output?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear where the value for `name` in the output comes from in your question, but let's assume for a moment that it is the first part until the underscore of the `name` from the input. The the following produces your required output:

```
.items | map(
  .metadata
  | select(.random_field."foo/foo" == "true")
  | { name: .name|split("_")|first, data: .name }
)
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "data": "test_data"
  }
]
```